# Multithreading in rabbitmq-library for java

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq

When i run this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
        MainRabbit main = new MainRabbit();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Connection connection = main.createConnection();
            Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
            channel.basicConsume("queueName", new CustomConsumer());
        }

    }


    private ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = createConnectionFactory();

    private ConnectionFactory createConnectionFactory() {
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHost("localhost");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    private Connection createConnection() throws IOException, TimeoutException {
        return connectionFactory.newConnection(es);
    }
```

I see that I have 2 separate threads for each tcp-connection to the rabbitmq. In the screenshot below, this is the AMQP Connection thread and the thread from the pool called "pool-2".

[image: screenshot from VisualVM]

Additionally, because I specified the value 2 in the ExecutorsService, then 2 more threads were created in the pool called "pool-1".

1. Where did "pool-2" come from?
2. What does es mean in `connectionFactory.newConnection(es)`?
   JavaDocs says "executor thread execution service for consumers on the connection".
   Does this mean that all consumers of this tcp-connection will work in a maximum of 2 threads in my example?
3. How to start processing incoming messages in several threads at once, so that, for example, 10 different messages from the same queue are processed in parallel?

Comment: execute main() with debugger line by line and watch how the number of threads increases

Answer (score 0):

Each connection in RabbitMQ (or rather in AMQP) is treated as a separate, bidirection stream of data. In thread-based languages is normal to associate a connection with a thread as well as not sharing threads among channels (that are "lightwight connections")

[docs from cloudamqp, well established rabbitmq-as-a-service provider](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2019-11-13-the-relationship-between-connections-and-channels-in-rabbitmq.html)

The main reason is to have independent workers for upstream and downstream message flows. This will prevent lagging on heavy-load conditions and backpressure mechanism will keep to works, since the client will continue to exchange ack messages

In general, however, you don't really need to set up multiple connections per client. Let your library do the job. You could be concerned because consumed messages trigger long running job, so multiplex them through a thread pool when they are received, each thread in the pool will process a message